# reading csv file format using python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read weather data from a csv formatted file. I printed the index and header of the file and i saw that the dates have index of zero. i tried using the datetime module in python to access the dates and it tells me there is an index error. Here is the error message i recieve:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "accra_weather.py", line 15, in <module>
    current_date = datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y-%m-%d")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is the full code:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

filename = "accra_month.csv"
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)

    dates, highs = [], []
    for row in reader:
        try:
           current_date = datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y-%m-%d")
           high = int(row[1])
        except ValueError:
            print(date, "Missing data")
        else:
            highs.append(high)
            dates.append(current_date)
```

This is also the weather data I am trying to examine:

```
GMT,Max TemperatureC,Mean TemperatureC,Min TemperatureC,Dew PointC,MeanDew PointC,Min DewpointC,Max Humidity, Mean Humidity, Min Humidity, Max Sea Level PressurehPa, Mean Sea Level PressurehPa, Min Sea Level PressurehPa, Max VisibilityKm, Mean VisibilityKm, Min VisibilitykM, Max Wind SpeedKm/h, Mean Wind SpeedKm/h, Max Gust SpeedKm/h,Precipitationmm, CloudCover, Events,WindDirDegrees
2017-6-1,33,29,26,26,24,23,94,78,56,1016,1014,1012,18,11,6,27,11,,0.00,2,,234
2017-6-2,32,29,26,26,26,25,94,83,62,1016,1014,1012,18,11,8,26,14,,0.00,3,,217
2017-6-3,31,28,26,26,26,22,94,86,61,1015,1012,1011,18,10,8,37,18,,0.76,5,Thunderstorm,214
```

Comment: Please show more of your code and less of the data. The error is in the code for reading the csv file, which is not included in the question.

Comment: Thank you. I also truncated the input file for brevity.

Comment: right. so what mistakes am i making in my code?

Comment: I don't know, actually. Your code works fine for me.

Comment: It does? so you are able to read the data and make the plots?

Comment: @user8277405 You probably have extra empty lines in your file. Those lines, when read by the `csv` module will return empty python lists. And, you cannot index an empty list. Take a look to make sure that there are no empty extra lines.

Comment: okay. I will try that

Comment: Oh great! That works fine. There was an extra empty line at the end of the file and i did not notice it. thanks for your help.